# Problem with IE and setInterval() not refreshing/updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, refresh, setinterval

I'm using JavaScript/Jquery to make a page auto-update with a value from a database, although it doesn't seem to update in Internet Explorer. It works fine in FireFox & Chrome. Can anyone explain what's wrong? It looks like IE is just displaying a cached version of the page. How can I prevent this happening? Thanks.

```
function updateComm() {  
 var url="commandSys.php";  
 jQuery("#theElement").load(url);  
}

setInterval("updateComm()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try disabling the cache with `ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
    cache: false
});

function updateComm() {  
 var url="commandSys.php";  
 jQuery("#theElement").load(url);  
}

setInterval(updateComm, 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can manually just append a `+new Date`  to `url` so it appends a query string to prevent caching.

Alternatively, disable caching on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks very much. I used the "ajaxSetup" solution. :)

Comment: yup, worked for me too, just copied and pasted the first part of this code into my file.

Comment: awesome, had the same issue with IE. The funny thing is, when open the developer tool then it worked. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Your php page is cached. Has nothing to do with the interval. Set the right caching headers on the page.