# What does SELECT *, MATCH mean?

Tags: php, mysql

I know `SELECT * FROM table` but I never saw `SELECT *, MATCH` before.

My working query is following

```
$query = $this->dbi
        ->prepare("SELECT *, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST (?) AS score FROM tmp_comments WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST(?)")
        ->execute($this->key,$this->key)
        ->results();
```

It does not work if I remove `,` after `SELECT *`

Please help me out, I tried a Google search but could not find anything.

Comment: MATCH is the function in class imported for database operations in your framework

Comment: A comma in the `SELECT` columnlist is just a separator. So, this gets all columns (as you would expect from `*`) and then also gets the result of the clause `MATCH(title, content) AGAINST (?) AS score`. So your question really is "what does `MATCH AGAINST` do"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically means that first print out all the columns of the desired resultset and then the match found(on the given rule).

See if the following example, makes it clear to you:

```
mysql> SELECT id, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Tutorial')
    -> FROM articles;
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Tutorial') |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 |                        0.65545833110809 |
|  2 |                                       0 |
|  3 |                        0.66266459226608 |
|  4 |                                       0 |
|  5 |                                       0 |
|  6 |                                       0 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

here an exempel

```
     SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST ('LU*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

from here
 [Problem with IE and setInterval() not refreshing/updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426510/problem-with-ie-and-setinterval-not-refreshing-updating)

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

There you go, it didn't take much googling

Answer (score 1):

MATCH is a mysql function. It's just another column in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is "get all the fields from all the tables in the query" (the "`*`" bit) and return the value of the [fulltext search query (the MATCH statement)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) as the "score" variable.

Incidentally, using `SELECT *` is potentially very inefficient unless you *really* need all of the fields. If possible, list the required fields via...

```
SELECT fieldname_a, fieldname_b, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST (?) AS score ...
```

By doing this, you won't be needlessly transferring data you don't require.

Answer (score 1):

`Select *` is used to select all the columns in the table. However in your case, the query is selecting all the columns in addition to the `relevancy figure` i.e. coming through using `MATCH(title, content) AGAINST (?) AS score`.

For more details on getting the relevancy/score through MATCH AGAINST query you can consult [FULLTEXT Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).